# How to make a custom response to my WebView with a IUriToStreamResolver

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I have made a Xamarin project with a WebView control. I want to show a custom error page when the user requests a file that is not found. But I can't get the IUriToStreamResolver to respond my custom error page. It only shows a empty page.

```
public class UriToStreamResolver : IUriToStreamResolver
{
    public UriToStreamResolver(IAppContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    IAppContext Context { get; set; }

    public IAsyncOperation<IInputStream> UriToStreamAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        string path = uri.AbsolutePath;

        // Because of the signature of the this method, it can't use await, so we 
        // call into a seperate helper method that can use the C# await pattern.
        return GetContent(path).AsAsyncOperation();
    }

    async Task<IInputStream> GetContent(string path)
    {
        // Fix path if it is pointing to the root
        if (path == "/")
            path = "/Index.html";

        // Try to get file 
        // Note: This is a custom call to my HybridWebView which handles OS-specific 
        // file I/O, the IFileInfo interface could be anything from a UWP StorageFile
        // to a Android File object. The interface just handles the GetStream() method.
        IFileInfo info = await Context.WebView.GetFileFromAssets(path);

        // Is the file found?
        if (info.Exists)
        {
            // Yes, return the stream => WORKING
            return (await info.GetStream()).AsRandomAccessStream();
        }
        else
        {
            // Else return some custom html => NOT WORKING
            var input = "<html><body>File not found</body></html>";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            return stream.AsRandomAccessStream();
        }
    }
}
```

Google search terms:

- WebView IUriToStreamResolver how to respond a string
- WebView IUriToStreamResolver memorystream not working
- WebView IUriToStreamResolver make a custom response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I can't get the IUriToStreamResolver to respond my custom error page. It only shows a empty page.

We can't make `AsRandomAccessStream` with text and pass it to `UriToStreamAsync` method. And for your scenario the better way is that include `Error.html` to the project. and load content from file like following.

```
 Uri appboundleURI = new Uri("ms-appx:///Error.html");
 StorageFile error = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(appboundleURI);
 IRandomAccessStream stream = await error.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
 return stream.GetInputStreamAt(0);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you elebrate why this would be a security issue? I'm trying to port my mvc webapp to xamarin and this is has turned out to be a really big obstacle. I've also tried hosting a webserver inside the app but that poses problems with android and ios. It needs to run offline, so i'm getting really desperate. I know about the hybrid webview, but that means changing a lot of code.

Comment: It's hard to explain, but we could make sure html storage file could be load by WebView with `IUriToStreamResolver` way.

Answer (score 2):

For some unknown reason, the UWP WebView refuses to load content from a managed MemoryStream. No matter how I tried wrapping it, it doesn't work, it can't be done.

The only way I found to solve this problem, was to use the method described here: https://blogs.infinitesquare.com/posts/windows/windows8-webview-navigatetolocalstreamuri-uritostreamresolver and do it with an InMemoryRandomAccessStream from WinRT.

```
async Task<IInputStream> GetContent(string path)
{
    if (path == "/")
        path = "/Index.html";

    IFileInfo info = await Context.WebView.GetFileFromAssets(path);

    if (info.Exists)
    {
        return (await info.GetStream()).AsRandomAccessStream();
    }
    else
    {
        var input = "<html><body>File not found</body></html>";
        
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream memoryStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        using (var dataWriter = new DataWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            dataWriter.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
            dataWriter.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian;

            dataWriter.WriteString(htmlString);
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            await dataWriter.FlushAsync();
            dataWriter.DetachStream();
        }

        return memoryStream.GetInputStreamAt(0);
    }
}
```